# I want to take users input & add it to an existing expandable listview. I want to trigger it through a FAB

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to take inputs from the user. There will be an edittext field and a button. After the user clicks it the listview will be updated.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear adapter and add new elements in it.For example;

```
myAdapter.clear();
mydapter.addAll(newArray);
```

This will update the listview. If you don't know adapters you can check [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take one List and add your data in the list, supply that list to adapter. Now when you again click on Add button then you only need to add new entry to your list and need to call

```
adapter.notifydatasetchange()
```

method will update your list entries with new one.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How do I trigger it from the floating action button?

Comment: Do you have click listener of the floating button? From click listener of the floating button add entry to list and call notifydatasetchange.